# How to add a function to an appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, append

I have an input-text. If you type something, the text appears below (see code snippet).

Now, **I need to** do the same with a previous step: clicking a button (preferably a checkbox) to append/remove all. Here is my failed idea: [DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoeRJy?editors=1010) (it appends the input text, but when you type, text won't apear below like it does on my code snippet).

I feel like the function to add text below does not work because there is a problem with selecting the appended element. How do I do this?

Any more simple idea to do this would be great

```js
var name1 = document.getElementById('name');

name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var result = document.querySelector('.X');
  
  console.log(this.value );
  result.innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>What is your name? </label><input type="text" id="name">

<p>Your name is: <span class="X"></span></p>
```

Comment: you can get an idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565086/splice-json-array-javascript/47565213#47565213), it's basically the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your first part of the snippet into appending logic while clicking the add button. As in your codes, the input box is appended to the document after its listener being attached.

```js
if (!added) {
  $content =  $(NewContent).appendTo('.firstappend');
 
  // attach listener after input box actually exists!
  var name1 = document.getElementById('A');
  name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var result = document.querySelector('span.Y');
    console.log(this.value );
    result.innerHTML = this.value;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  let NewContent = '<div class="added">' +
    '<p>' +
    '<label>What is your name? </label>' +
    '<input type="text" id="A">' +
    '</p>' +
    '<p>Your name is: <span class="Y"></span></p>' +
    '</div>';
  $(".addremove").on('click', function() {
    if ($(".added").length) {
      $(".added").remove();
    } else {
      $(".firstappend").append(NewContent);

    }
  });

  $(document).on('change keyup', '#A', function(event) {
    $("span.Y").html($(event.currentTarget).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toadd">
  <button type="button" class="addremove">Do you have a name?</button>
</div>

<div class="firstappend"></div>
```

as from the DEMO you included,
appended elements to document cannot be invoked explicitly, since you're using jQuery, you can do this

```
$(document).on('change keyup', '#A', function(event) {
  $("span.Y").html($(event.currentTarget).val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I noticed from your code snippet that if you type only a letter, it won't appear until you type the next one. For example, if you type "Robert" it only shows "Rober"